# How to inject singleton?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I was making a quick sample to get used to Dagger2 but I got stuck at one point.
I have a class that I want to be a singleton, but Dagger2 keeps giving me different objects.

Here's my source code:

SingletonClass

```
public class SingletonClass {

}
```

SingletonComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { SingletonModule.class })
public interface SingletonComponent {
    SingletonClass singleton();
}
```

SingletonModule

```
@Module
public class SingletonModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SingletonClass provideSingletonClass() {
        return new SingletonClass();
    }
}
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SingletonClass comp = DaggerSingletonComponent.create().singleton();
    System.out.println("singleton: " + comp);
    comp = DaggerSingletonComponent.create().singleton();
    System.out.println("singleton: " + comp);  
}
```

But I'm getting different objects logged to the stdout.
Any ideas why?

Comment: where is body of DaggerSingletonComponent.create() and singleton()

Comment: @AshishNegi It's generated

Comment: It seems to me that .create() is creating a NEW singleton. Is there may be a get() instead? I am not very familiar with Dagger.

Comment: @Knossos AFAIK, it should be handled internally by the dagger2 lib

Comment: Try using get() anyway. It is conceivable that someone would want to create a brand new instance.

Comment: @Knossos there's no get, but I found what was wrong, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a stupid mistake, but I'll leave an answer should somebody stumble upon such a problem.

What I was doing was creating **new graphs, instead of requesting an instance** from the previously created graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
@Module
public class SingletonModule {
    private SingletonClass sing = new SingletonClass();

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SingletonClass provideSingletonClass() {
        return sing;
    }
}
```